# Formula field value not to change while cloning when the reference object value changed

Tags: formula-field

I have the below formula field , in Quote object, which is a reference from another object " RedBook"

[image]

But i want that, while cloning the quote, the field value remains teh same i.2 here 30 / 26 even if the original value from the referred object changed to some other value. I tried workflow & process builder, but not able to accomplish it. whereas first time while creation it should trigger the formula reference value, but while cloning it should remains the same. Can i change my formula field to accomplish this. As of now my formula field is, below i.e exactly the same reference value from the other object.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to

1. Change the field type from Formula to Text
2. Add a field checkbox isClone (default value **false**) on the Quote object
3. Create/Update a trigger on Quote, (in before update/create) check if you're in the clone function (see the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707328/detect-when-a-record-is-being-cloned-in-trigger)). **If yes, copy the value Model_Description__r.Premium_Group__c to your new Text Field** and put the checkbox isClone to **True**
4. Create a process (in process builder) on Model_Description__c. When the object is updated on the field Premium_Group__c, update the related Quote(s) with the new value for Premium_Group__c (except the cloned ones, check on isClone)

Why the trigger ? To ensure that you keep the old value of the original object.

Why the process ? So that you mimic the formula function on your original objects, but not on your clones